# Tópicos no central de ajuda não traduzidos

Tags: debate, tradução

Precisei acessar o [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para agregar informações à um comentário de uma pergunta e me deparei com os seguintes tópicos *não traduzidos*, não sei se eles realmente deveriam ser mantidos nesse idioma, mas acho válido trazer para vocês.
 Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]